# Dock and Terminal don't work on systems with home directory on different versions of OSX

Tags: macos, dock, nfs

I have two macs, one running Mavericks and one running El Capitan. Most of the users on both of the machines have their home directory in an external server connected by NFS. When I try to launch Terminal.app from a user with a remote home directory, it doesn't start up. When I try to remove an item from the dock, the dock freezes and I can't do anything until I log out and then log back in again.

What is causing these issues, and how can I fix them?

Comment: Did you check /var/log/syslog? It may give you a hint (which you can share with us).

Comment: open Console.app and take a look at the Terminal and the Dock Log maybe you can see there what exactly causes the Terminal to fail opening and  Dock to freeze